# MySQL and Apache won't start in non-vm XAMPP on Mac

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

Previously I was trying to set up a local wordpress website with XAMPP virtual machine, and servers all ran without problem, but I kept getting 403s and 404s in the browser. I switched to the non vm XAMPP, but MySQL and Apache both don't start. I looked up solutions and tried

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

And got the error

```
..XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server: line 264: kill: (37369) - No such process ERROR!
```

And for Apache I tried

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

and start but neither worked. Any idea what could be wrong, or why the vm version of XAMPP can start the servers but the other doesn't?